# Incrementing a variable within a string in csh

Tags: linux, csh

I'm writing a script in csh (it needs to be in csh)
and I've really been struggling on what seems like a trivial problem.
I want to set an environment variable with string containing a numeric variable.  However I want to increment the value being stored without affecting the value.  Is this possible.  I've spent quite a while digging through csh tutorials and I'm at a loss.
Below is the last iteration of what I have tried.  Nothing seems to work.

```
set LOG_HIST = 8
setenv LOG_FILE "/foo/log/foo."${LOG_FILE}".log"
setenv NEXT_LOG_FILE "/foo/log/foo."(${LOG_FILE} + 1)".log"
```

Comment: Also see [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the backticks to get the output of a command and use `expr` to evaluate an arithmetical expression:

```
% set LOG_HIST = 8
% setenv LOG_FILE "/foo/log/foo."${LOG_HIST}".log"
% setenv NEXT_LOG_FILE "/foo/log/foo."`expr ${LOG_HIST} + 1`.log
% echo $NEXT_LOG_FILE
/foo/log/foo.9.log
```